# Flutter: Create predefined colors throw error

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to create a class where I can predefine colors which i then use inside my project. This code was copied from another tutorial and worked before, however I now receive error using `LinearGradient`but with no error explanation. The constructor of the method takes a colors argument:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Palette {
  static const Color scaffold = Color(0xFFF0F2F5);
  static const Color facebookBlue = Color(0xFF1777F2);
  static const LinearGradient createRoomGradient = LinearGradient(
    colors: [Color(0xFF496AE1), Color(0xFFCE48B1)],
  );

  static const Color online = Color(0xFF4BCB1F);

  static const LinearGradient storyGradient = LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black26],
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this code in dartpad. It isn't creating any issue.

Comment: okay strange, restarting VSCode resolved the problem somehow...